# Render the results of two separate async.each methods

Tags: node.js, async.js

I am new to nodejs and async. Having trouble understanding how can I wrap the two separate async.each methods to have one res.render...I am trying to display a list of valid account ids, and valid user ids on the front end.
The two separate async.each methods are:

```
async.each(account_ids, function(accountId, callback) {
        console.log('Processing accountId ' + accountId);

        callingExternalApi(accountId, callback, function(err, response){
          if(err){
            console.log("error account");
          }
          console.log("account response is: ", response);
        });

      }, function(err) {
        if( err ) {
          console.log('An account failed to process');
        } else {
          console.log('All accounts have been processed successfully');
        }
      });
```

and

```
async.each(email_ids, function(emailId, callback) {
        console.log('Processing email id ' + emailId);
        request({
          url: emailIdlookupUrl,
          method: 'POST',
          json: {
            email_address: emailId
          }
        }, function (err, response, body) {
          if (err) {
            logger.error(err);
            req.flash('error', err.message);
            return res.redirect('?');
          }
          if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
            const msg = 'Unable to verify user';
            req.flash('error', msg);
            return res.redirect('?');
          }
          console.log("user id is: ", body.user.id);
          callback();
        });

      }, function(err) {
        if( err ) {
          console.log('An email failed to process');
        } else {
          console.log('All user emails have been processed successfully');
        }
      });
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Please excuse me for any redundant callbacks or error logging. Still learning nodejs.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is not that you are invoking both of these async.each calls. The problem is that they will run in parallel, and the fastest one to invoke req.* functions or callback function will return a response to the connection.

Both of these functions return promises if their callback parameters are omitted.

I recommend reading up on both the async library and JS async/await in general:

- https://javascript.info/async-await
- https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#each
- https://zellwk.com/blog/async-await-express/

Note that async also accepts native async functions, which many finder cleaner and easier to understand.

Here is what I think you want from the code above, including compiling the results into lists:

```
var request = require("request-promise");

async function checkAccounts(account_ids) {
  const valid_accounts = [];
  await async.each(account_ids, async function(accountId) {
    console.log("Processing accountId " + accountId);
    const extAPIresult = await callingExternalApi(accountId);
    console.log("account response is: ", extAPIresult);
  });
  valid_accounts.push(extAPIresult);
  console.log("All accounts have been processed successfully");
  return valid_accounts;
}

async function checkEmails(email_ids) {
  const valid_emails = [];
  await async.each(email_ids, async function(emailId) {
    console.log("Processing email id " + emailId);
    const reqresult = await request({
      url: emailIdlookupUrl,
      method: "POST",
      json: {
        email_address: emailId
      }
    });
    if (reqresult.statusCode !== 200) {
      throw new Error("Unable to verify user");
    }
    valid_emails.push(reqresult.body.user.id);
    console.log("user id is: ", reqresult.body.user.id);
  });
  console.log("All emails have been processed successfully");
  return valid_emails;
}

async function doChecks() {
  const accounts = checkAccounts(account_ids);
  const emails = checkEmails(email_ids);
  const responses = await Promises.all([accounts, emails]);
  console.log("All checks have been processed successfully");
  return responses;
}

function get(req, res) {
  doChecks()
    .then(responses => {
      res.send("All checks have been processed successfully");
      res.send(String(responses));
    })
    .catch(err => {
      req.flash("error", err.message);
      res.redirect("?");
    });
}
```